# How to make the argument of `regular polygon sides` into a macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, shapes

I am drawing a regular pentadecagon (i.e. 15-gon) using `tikz` and the `shapes.geometric` Ti*k*Z library. And I went with this (simplified):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node [
        draw, regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides = 15
    ] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Everything is fine, until I came up with the idea of wrapping the "magic number" 15 into  macro. I did this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\sides{15}    
    \node [
        draw, regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides = \sides
    ] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Boom!!!

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.12     ] at (0,0) {};
```

I also tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*\sides{15}    
    \node [
        draw, regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides = \sides
    ] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it boomed exactly the same way. So:

1. Why is this not working? I do not quite understand :(
2. What, then, should I do?

I considered putting a `\tikzset{regular polygon sides = 15}`, but since I need to use the magic number somewhere else, I can't use this approach unless I can later extract this number.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: For your information, `\newcommand*` is essentially just `\def` with ensuring that the macro is not already defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution of the puzzle: look in `pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex` and find that `\sides` is already used internally:

```
683 % Shape Regular Polygon.
684 %
685 \pgfdeclareshape{regular polygon}{%
686     \savedmacro\sides{%
687         \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sides{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/regular polygon sides}}%
688     }%
```

(line numbers added for locating the code). Thus redefining `\sides` will most likely have adverse effects on processing the code. On page 1112 of the PGF manual we see

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the `math` `tikzlibrary`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,math}
\tikzmath{
let \n=15;} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [
        draw, regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides = \n
    ] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it still booms when I compile it :(

Comment: However, all is good if I use another name like `\sidesss` instead of `\sides`... Interesting behavior :P

Comment: @L.F. Initially I have used `\n` for side numbers and it has compiled without error. Later I have decided to edit my answer to use the name you have chosen but without trying to compile to code. So sorry!

Answer (score 3):

@egreg explained you very nicely why the error is there, and here is a simple way how to use `\sides` nevertheless. You only need to add the `.expanded` key.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*\sides{15}    
    \node [
        draw, regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides/.expanded=\sides
    ] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works! If only I were able to accept two answers!